# alert part of AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I am using JS to submit data without loading the page and it is working fine, on response i am trying to send JSON which looks like this

```
{"mes":"<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Your goal has been updated.<\/div>","graph_data":"[['07\/9\/2014',500],['07\/8\/2014',900],['07\/7\/2014',1200],['07\/6\/2014',500],['07\/5\/2014',500],['07\/4\/2014',500],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000]]"}
```

There are two items in the JSON response `mes` and `graph_data`. Now how can i make use of `graph_data` and `mes` seperately?

If I do this `alert(data);` this shows the above JSON response

But if I do the following I cant get them to alert seperately.

```
alert(data.graph_data);
alert(data.mes);
```

I will really appreciate if anyone can guide me on how to separate the two.

**Update**

This is the JS i am using to send and retrieve data on click of a button

```
$('#goalgraphdatasubmit').click(function () {
    $('#goalgraphupdateform').submit();
});
$('#goalgraphupdateform').submit(function (e) {
    "use strict";
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("goalgraphdatasubmit").innerHTML = "saving..";
    var post = $('#goalgraphupdateform').serialize();
    var action = $('#goalgraphupdateform').attr('action');
    $("#holiday_goal_message").slideUp(350, function () {
        $('#holiday_goal_message').hide();
        $.post(action, post, function (data) {
            $('#holiday_goal_message').html(data);
            document.getElementById('holiday_goal_message').innerHTML = data;
            $('#holiday_goal_message').slideDown('slow');
            document.getElementById("goalgraphdatasubmit").innerHTML = "Submit";
            alert(data);
            if (data == '<div class="alert alert-success">Your goal has been updated.</div>') {

                //$('#divGoal').load('dashboard-goals.php');
                $("#holiday_goal_message").hide(2000);
                updatetestGraph();
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: You probably don't have the JSON parsed.  Add `dataType: 'json'` to your AJAX call.  P.S. Don't use `alert` as a debugging tool, use `console.log`.

Comment: Sounds like your JSON isn't structured as you think **or** the response isn't actually being parsed as JSON. Setting aside the obvious (escaped HTML as a message, using `alert` for debugging), create a fiddle or similar with your code and we can see where the JSON response is going awry.

Comment: I dont think it has to do with structure even if i take a simple example like this `$test = array('mes'=>'Your goal has been updated.'); json_encode($test);` and try to `alert(data.mes),` it does not work

Comment: you're double encoding your json graphData doesn't need to be jsonEncoded twice (it also needs to be valid json).. Additionally, it would probably be cleaner to return the message text rather than the alert html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Like

```
var data = JSON.parse('{"event1":{"title":"My birthday","start":"12\/27\/2011 10:20 ","end":"12\/27\/2011 00:00 "},"event2":{"title":"My birthday again","start":"12\/27\/2011 10:20 ","end":"12\/27\/2011 00:00 "}}');

arr = []
for(var event in data){
    var dataCopy = data[event]
    for(key in dataCopy){
        if(key == "start" || key == "end"){
            // needs more specific method to manipulate date to your needs
            dataCopy[key] = new Date(dataCopy[key])
        }
    }
    arr.push(dataCopy)
}

alert( JSON.stringify(arr) )
```

[Demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/HkEuf/2506/)
[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/ashuslove/HkEuf/2518/)

Comment: Thanks for taking time and providing the answer, however I dont understand it. It still alerts both events `My birthday` and `my birthday again`

Comment: in var dataCopy, you will the the event1, event2 etc and in key you will the child items i.e title, start etc.

Comment: I still don't understand,  can you update the fiddle with just event 1 alert

Comment: i have updated the demo and it's giving you all the start date in alert.

Answer (score 0):

> Sorry cannot comment so have to answer

I have taken your JSON string in a variable here and it gives me proper result
[See here](http://jsfiddle.net/8gMw3/)

```
 var d = {"mes":"<div class=\"alert alert-success\">Your goal has been updated.    <\/div>","graph_data":"[['07\/9\/2014',500],['07\/8\/2014',900],['07\/7\/2014',1200],['07\/6\/2014',500],['07\/5\/2014',500],['07\/4\/2014',500],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000],['07\/11\/2014',2000]]"};
 alert(d.graph_data);
 alert(d.mes);
```